# find parameter value when polynomial has three roots

Tags: polynomials

For which value of parameter $a$ This polynominal has three different real roots $P(x)=x^3+ax+2$

I thought about using here vieta formula and solve system of equation but i wonder if there are different methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discriminant of a cubic equation $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0\;$ is
$$\Delta = 18 a b c d  - 4b^3d + b^2 c^2 -4ac^3 - 27 a^2 d^2.$$

- If $\Delta > 0,$ then the equation has three distinct real roots.
- If $\Delta = 0,$ then the equation has a multiple root and all its roots are real.
- If $\Delta < 0,$ then the equation has one real root and two nonreal complex conjugate roots

Use the above result you will get your answer very easily.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

If $\displaystyle P(x)=0$ a repeated root $u,P'(u)=0$